# Strategy to simulate events in object under test

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

BRAND NEW to unit testing, I mean really new.  I've read quite a bit and am moving slowly, trying to follow best practices as I go.  I'm using MS-Test in Visual Studio 2010.

I have come up against a requirement that I'm not quite sure how to proceed on.  I'm working on a component that's responsible for interacting with external hardware.  There are a few more developers on this project and they don't have access to the hardware so I've implemented a "dummy" or simulated implementation of the component and moved as much shared logic up into a base class as possible.

Now this works fine as far as allowing them to compile and run the code, but it's not terrible useful for simulating the events and internal state changes needed for my unit tests (don't forget I'm new to testing)

For example, there are a couple events on the component that I want to test, however I need them to be invoked in order to test them.  Normally to raise the event I would push a button on the hardware or shunt two terminals, but in the simulated object (obviously) I can't do that.

There are two concerns/requirements that I have:

1. I need to provide state changes and raise events for my unit tests
2. I need to provide state changes and raise events for my team to test dependencies on the component (e.g. a button on a WPF view becomes enabled when a certain hardware event occurs)

For the latter I thought about some complicated control panel dialog that would let me trigger events and generally simulate hardware operation and user interaction.  This is complicated as it requires a component with no message pump to provide a window with controls.  Stinky.  Or another approach could be to implement the simulated component to take a "StateInfo" object that I could use to change the internals of the object.

This can't be a new problem, I'm sure many of you have had to do something similar to this and I'm just wondering what patterns or strategies you've used to accomplish this.  I know I can access private fields with a n accessor, but this doesn't really provide an interactive (in the case of runtime simulation) changes.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an interface on the library you use to interact with the external hardware you can just create a mock object for it and raise events from that in your unit tests.

If there isn't, then you'll need to wrap the hardware calls in a wrapper class so you mock it and provide the behaviours you want in your test.

For examples of how to raise events from mock objects have a look at [Mocking Comparison - Raising Events](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/08/mocking-comparison-part-10-events.html)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Sounds like "mock objects" are what I've been calling "dummy objects" all this time ;)
The struggle now is how to design your objects to avoid heavy duplication of code from actual implementations and mock objects.  In other words, if the systems that raise the events are complex I would need to duplicate it in the mock object in order to test it.  This of course will create a maintenance issue.  I suppose moving as much functionality as possible into a base class would help, but it still seems as though there will be heavy duplication.

Comment: I had a long comment written about how I was still stumped but then at the end I had my "A-ha moment".  Your statement:
"...you'll need to wrap the hardware calls in a wrapper class so you mock it..." is the key.

Tell me if I have this correct:
1. Create an interface for the hardware SDK wrapper object (e.g. IHardware)
2. Make changes to my object I want to test to have an instance of IHardware somehow injected (currently it's not using any DI)
3. Create a mock implementation of IHardware which exposes state properties and method to set internal state
4. (next comment)

Comment: 4. Find some way to have the unit test inject the mock object instead of the actual object
5. Call methods and set properties on the mock object to simulate my hardware events

Man... that's a lot of extra effort in order to test something.  Although if this is indeed the appropriate strategy for this type of situation then I will learn from it and use it from the get go next time.
So do I have all this correct?

Comment: Your steps are largely correct and yes, it's a little work but it's not too hard.  Just start with the interface containing the methods you actually need to call and then build it up over time.