# How do I create a an instance of a type with a private constructor for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, mspec

I need to unit test an event handler that responds to the SerialDataReceived event of `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`. This event handler has the signature

```
void SerialDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
```

So when my unit test calls into the method, it needs a `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs` instance. But that object has a private constructor. So how do I get a `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs` to pass into the method?

I'm sure I must be missing an obvious technique here, I have had a long day... Any advice please?

Comment: Could you use a mocking framework to mock the event?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045776/strategy-to-simulate-events-in-object-under-test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an instance of the desired type using reflection:

```
var args = typeof(SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
  .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new [] { typeof(SerialData) }, null)
  .Invoke(new object[] { SerialData.Chars });
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I knew adding that MSpec tag would pay off ;-) After spending a lot of time investigating Moles, I came up with a slightly different solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create instances of classes with private constructors directly. You could use reflection to do it, but that is a pretty nasty solution.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually refactored my code to eliminate the private constructor, like this:

```
    private void HandleSerialDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialDataReceived(sender, e.EventType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   This method executes in response to the <see cref="ISerialPort.DataReceived"/> event
    ///   via <see cref="HandleSerialDataReceived"/> and is called on its own worker thread.
    /// </summary>
    internal void SerialDataReceived(object sender, SerialData eventType)
    {
     ...
    }
```

So now I can do my unit testing on `SerialDataReceived` and pass it the `SerialData` parameter directly.

However, I think I prefer Alexander's solution because it doesn't require me to re-factor my production code.